# Eval error in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, eval, boo

In the same place this works:

```
Debug.Log(gameObject);
```

And this produces BCE0020: Boo.Lang.Compiler.CompilerError: An instance of type 'UnityEngine.Component' is required to access non static member 'gameObject'.

```
eval("Debug.Log(gameObject);");
```

This works:

```
Debug.Log(this.gameObject);
```

And this prints 'Null'

```
eval("Debug.Log(this.gameObject);");
```

Why? What is the problem with non-static members?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should code,

```
var me = this;
eval("Debug.Log(me.gameObject)");
```

or use `bind()` method.